# Save number format by default in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to save number format with comma delimiter as default in Excel.
So number 123456.78 will always look like 123,456.78

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Excel general number formatting is based on your locale. This contains a "Digit grouping symbol", filling this is will change your format accordingly.

Be aware this is not only done for Excel, but for every application on your computer, based on this format.

Answer (score 1):

Home/Styles:  Right click on Normal and select Modify

Change the Number style

- from General either to Number + use thousands separator
- or, if you want to use Scientific notation when over a certain amount, perhaps

`[<100000000]#,##0.00;General`

- or whatever you want.